Does any embassy like US, UK or Schengen scrutinize where the purchases are made showing in a bank statement?
Does any embassy like US, UK or Schengen scrutinize where the purchases are made showing in a bank statement?
For example of someone pays for regular counselling or therapy by ATM card it would show in the bank statement. Is it a problem if trying to get a tourist visa?

If you make a purchase at “the little terrorist bazaar” they would probably have a problem with it. Seeing a doctor or therapist, that would seem extremely unlikely to me.

And they probably won't look into what the therapist specialises in to get an idea what kind of problem it is that you're consulting them about. I find it hard to imagine any set of circumstances where that would give any kind of information that would be useful in determining whether they should issue a visa.

Visa issuers are concerned with making sure a) you have enough money to fund the proposed trip b) said money was obtained legally c) the amount you propose to spend on the trip is proportionate to your personal circumstances. They’re not likely to look into where you spend your money, assuming none of the transactions look as if they’re eg illegal, or raise concerns about your intentions for the visit. See this related question

And even if they did care, something like counseling/therapy could just as well show up as a positive as a negative. It is possibly (but very unlikely) to increase the perceived risk of needing to rely on medical support, but so long as you have insurance that's minimal. But it also demonstrates a tie to your existing life that would be highly disruptive to abandon. And that's the kind of thing that gives the immigration officers confidence that you will return home.

Seeing a therapist about a problem might give a person some tools to cope with certain challenges, and thereby lowering the risk of needing to rely on medical support.
